# yarn updating package version with git tag message

Tags: npm, version, yarnpkg, semantic-versioning

I know that npm can set the git tag message when updating a package version like this

```
npm version patch -m "Upgrade to %s for reasons"
```

how can we do that in yarn?

Answer (score 4):

According to [the documentation](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/version/#toc-git-tags), you can do it by setting setting your yarn configuration.

```
yarn config set version-git-message "Upgrade to %s for reasons"
```

There does not appear to be a documented command-line option. One workaround might be to run the command above before running `yarn version` and then running a `yarn config` command to unset `version-git-message`. It may also be possible to use `git` hooks to achieve what you need.